# How to store data from .txt files separated with commas ignoring the empty space behind commas

Tags: java, split

I have two problems.

1. So, the .txt file is like this:

`1, 2, 2.0, car, 3, 4,20, house, 7, 8.2, 19, movie, 3,1, 45`

I need to separate these numbers and words, and put them into separate lists, but it only works when I use the `.split(", ");` method, and it's not putting the numbers which have no empty space behind commas into my numbers list. My code:

```
File file = new File(pathToFile); 

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String str; 
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {

        data = str.split(", ");
    }

for (String entry : data) {
    try {
            int number = Integer.valueOf(entry);
            numbersList.add(number);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            wordsList.add(entry);
        }
    }

System.out.println(numbersList);
System.out.println(wordsList);
```

I've read somewhere that the `.split();` method is automatically ignoring empty spaces, but that does not seem to be the case, because I'm getting this output:

`numbersList - 1, 2, 3, 7, 19, 45`

`wordsList - 2.0, car, 4,20, house, 8.2, movie, 3,1`

2. I need help with separating floats from words. So far, I've tried this:

   ```
   try {
       int number = Integer.valueOf(entry);
       float decimalNumber = Float.parseFloat(entry);
       numbersList.add(number);
       decimalNumbersList.add(decimalNumber);
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

       wordsList.add(entry);
   }
   ```

   But it didn't work. At all. It just converted the normal numbers to floats.

`decimalNumbersList - 1.0, 2.0, 24.0, 18.0, 1.0, 3.0, 20.0, 12.0, 8.0, 12.0`

Comment: Split by "," then use String's `trim` method to remove whitespace

Comment: @DustinNieffenegger works good, but FAEWZX's answer is better suited for my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first part, I decided to simply remove the white spaces and then parse by "," . But other good approaches were suggested, those are good as well.

To separate float from the Strings, I go through each data entry and check if it contains the float delimeter symbol ("."). If it does, check it is a float and add it to the numbers list. Notice `numbersList` is an `ArrayList<Number>`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("path");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String str;
        String[] data = null;
        ArrayList<Number> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Remove white space and split by comma
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
            data = str.split(",");
        }

        assert data != null;
        for (String entry : data) {

            //check for floats
            if(entry.contains(".")){
                try {
                    //Check if we can parse 
                    float d = Float.parseFloat(entry);
                    //Add to numbers list.
                    numbersList.add(d);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            //Else, handle the rest
            } else {
                try {
                    int number = Integer.valueOf(entry);
                    numbersList.add(number);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    wordsList.add(entry);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numbersList);
        System.out.println(wordsList);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex

```
data = str.split(", ?");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like basically you want to create separate list for all types of elements. I would use below approach to create separate list for all datatypes in your program:

```
for (String entry : data) {
  if(isInteger(entry))
    numbersList.add(Integer.valueOf(entry));
  else if(isDouble(entry))
    doublesList.add(Double.valueOf(entry));
  else
    wordsList.add(entry);
}

System.out.println(numbersList);
System.out.println(wordsList);
System.out.println(doublesList);
```

Here's the definition of `isInteger` and `isDouble` function

```
boolean isInteger(String input){
   try {
       Integer.parseInt(input);
       return true;
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
   }
}

boolean isDouble(String input){
   try {
       Double.parseDouble(input);
       return true;
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
   }
}
```

**Alternate Approach**

If you can read using `Scanner` class then it would be even simple problem by using `hasNextInt` and `nextInt` method.

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt())
  numbersList.add(scanner.nextInt());
else if (scanner.hasNextDouble())
  doublesList.add(scanner.nextDouble());
else
  wordsList.add(scanner.next());
```

For splitting you can use `str.split(", ?")` as suggested in other answer.

Comment: the boolean methods way works good, but I'm looking for something more subtle... vs97's answer is more suited to my problems, but thanks for your time and help, it's good to have a few different view angles to a solution

Comment: Yes you are right but above solution should work fine as well, there were few typos before which I fixed now. That might be reason you had some issues while running it.